# How to parse URLs and phone numbers out of my static data and render them as clickable Linking items

Tags: javascript, react-native, hyperlink

I am building my very first React Native app using Expo. I have a FAQs section in my app where I am rendering questions and answers with an Accordion component. The Accordion component is being populated with a predefined static data set. When the user selects a question, the answer expands below it, and collapses when another question is selected. The Accordion is working well, however, in some of the given answers there are suggested links to follow.

**Right now these links are rendering as static strings. I am trying to get them to render as clickable links.**

Here is an example of my code:

**Accordion Component**

```react
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Text,View,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';
import data from './DataSet.js

const AccordionList = ({data}) => {

  // Default active selector
  const [activeSections, setActiveSections] = useState([]);

  const setSections = (sections) => {
    //setting up a active section state
    setActiveSections(sections.includes(undefined) ? [] : sections);
  };

  const renderHeader = (section, _, isActive) => {
    //Accordion Header view - Questions
    return (
      <Animatable.View
        duration={400}
        style={[styles.header, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}
        transition="backgroundColor">
           <Text style={styles.headerText}>

               {section.title}{/* <---Renders Question */}

           </Text>
      </Animatable.View>
    );
  };

  const renderContent = (section, _, isActive) => {
    //Accordion Content view - Answers
    return (
      <Animatable.View
        duration={400}
        style={[styles.content, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}
        transition="backgroundColor">
        <Animatable.Text
          animation={isActive ? 'bounceIn' : undefined}
          style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>

              {section.content} {/* <---Renders Answer */}

        </Animatable.Text>
      </Animatable.View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
          <Accordion
            activeSections={activeSections}
            sections={data}
            touchableComponent={TouchableOpacity}
            renderHeader={renderHeader}
            renderContent={renderContent}
            duration={400}
            onChange={setSections}
          />
    </View>

  );
};

export default AccordionList;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "black",

  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    padding: 15,
    marginTop:10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginHorizontal:10,
  },
  headerText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  content: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginHorizontal:10,
    textAlign:'right',
    lineHeight:1.5
  },
  inactive: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
  },
  active: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(245,252,255,1)',
  },

  selectTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '500',
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color:"#efefef"
  },


});
```

**DataSet.js**

```react
data:[
    {
        title:"What is Ameelio?",
        content:"Ameelio is a nonprofit service that allows friends and families to send letters, postcards, games and more for free through their mobile application."
    },
    {
        title:"What can I do on Ameelio?",
        content:"Yes. You may call customer service any time at 1 (800) 555-5555"
    },
    {
        title:"Where can I find more information?",
        content:"You can find more information on https://ameelio.org."
    },
    {
        title:"How do I get the Ameelio app?",
        content:"Navigate to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ameelio.letters_mobile to download the free app."
    },
]
```

In summary, I am trying to figure out **how to parse URLs and phone numbers out of my static data and render them as clickable Linking items**.

Comment: Also, I am developing in a unique coding environment where I do not have full access to the internet. I do not have unlimited access to Google or GitHub. I have a finite set of whitelisted resources to utilize: StackOverflow is one of these resources So if you could please explain your answer and refrain from directing me to a link I will most likely not be able to follow, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: A small hint maybe helps! 
- Try using  Two Regular Expression Conditions to match either the Url/Phone.
- You will split your sentence according to of the match condition, and tag this as URL/ Phone
--- Example:
let sentenceArray = []
if condition matches phone:
   sentenceArray.push({sentence:"Text goes here", tag:"phone})
....

- Then while rendering your sentence array you can assign it to TouchableOpacity and Linking Library, or render it in a normal TextView.

Comment: I was thinking about a similar solution...I am not sure where to put this functionality. How would I dynamically add it back into my rendered text?

Comment: You would have a TextView which embeds many other TextViews, the one which is a link, you can style differently and add onPress to it, https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#onpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using `react-native-hyperlink`.

```
...
import Hyperlink from "react-native-hyperlink";
...
```

```
...
    //Accordion Content view - Answers
    return (
      <Animatable.View
        accessible
        accessibilityLabel={section.content}
        duration={400}
        style={[styles.content, isActive ? styles.active : styles.inactive]}
        transition="backgroundColor"
      >
        <Hyperlink linkDefault linkStyle={{ color: "#2980b9", fontSize: 20 }}>
          <Animatable.Text
            accessibilityRole="text"
            animation={isActive ? "bounceIn" : undefined}
            style={styles.contentText}
          >
            {section.content}
          </Animatable.Text>
        </Hyperlink>
      </Animatable.View>
    );
...
```